# Can't seem to move <span> element

Tags: css, html

I want to move my text to:

[image: a]

Here is my code/markup:

http://scratchpad.io/supreme-behavior-5616

Answer (score 0):

Just add

```
img {
  float: left;
}
```

to your img CSS.
http://scratchpad.io/supreme-behavior-5616

Comment: how would I then move the <span> element down?

Comment: @user3133281 **down** where?